# Uitable view cell duplicating issue swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a chat application in which i am creating speech bubbles. The issue happens to the cell as it's overlapped while scrolling UITableView. I have tried many solutions , but all of them didn't work.

My code is below:

```
var cell:chatBubble? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell1") as? chatBubble

if cell == nil {
                                                   
    tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "chatBubble", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")

    let arrNib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("chatBubble",owner: self, options: nil)!
    cell = arrNib.first as? chatBubble
}
let green = UIColor(red: 179/255, green: 52/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 1)

if (arrCell.contains(indexPath.row)) {
    print("Exist")
} else {
    arrCell.append(indexPath.row)
    print("Not exist")
                                               
    cell!.showOutgoingMessage(color: green, text: self.animals[indexPath.row], tag: indexPath.row)
}
```

**UITableviewCell**

```
func showOutgoingMessage(color: UIColor, text: String, tag: Int) {
            
    lblmsg.numberOfLines = 0
    lblmsg.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    lblmsg.textColor = .white
    lblmsg.text = text
    lblmsg.tag = tag
                    
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: 0.66 * self.frame.width,
                                                height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = text.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                      options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                      attributes: [.font: lblmsg.font],
                      context: nil)
    lblmsg.frame.size = CGSize(width: ceil(boundingBox.width),
                               height: ceil(boundingBox.height))
                    
    let bubbleImageSize = CGSize(width: lblmsg.frame.width + 20,
                                 height: lblmsg.frame.height + 20)
                
    outgoingMessageView = UIImageView(frame:
                         CGRect(x: self.lblmsg.frame.origin.x,
                                y: self.lblmsg.frame.origin.y,
                                         width: bubbleImageSize.width,
                                         height: bubbleImageSize.height))
    outgoingMessageView.tag = tag
            
    let bubbleImage = UIImage(named: "incoming-message-bubble")?
                       
                        .resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 17, left: 21, bottom: 17, right: 21),
                                        resizingMode: .stretch)
                        .withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
                    
                    outgoingMessageView.image = bubbleImage
                    outgoingMessageView.tintColor = color
            self.addSubview(outgoingMessageView)
    }
```

I have used following function to solve repeated cells,but it clears
both 1st and 8th cell(reused cell). i just want to clear things in repeated cell.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.lblmsg.text = nil
    self.outgoingMessageView.image = nil    
} 
                        
[![cell repeat][1]][1]





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRAi4.png
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough info for people to be able to help with the issue you're describing. There are also at least 5 issues (detailed in the answer below) that need to be resolved here before that extra information can be useful, and even then, there will probably be another 5-10 issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, that resolve fully your issue, but after review your code I have a couple suggestions.

1. Move nib registration outside of cellForRow function, for example to viewDidLoad of your controller:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "chatBubble", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
}
```

2. Update dequeueReusableCell code from

```swift
var cell:chatBubble? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell1") as? chatBubble

if cell == nil {
                                                   
    tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "chatBubble", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")

    let arrNib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("chatBubble",owner: self, options: nil)!
    cell = arrNib.first as? chatBubble
}
```

to

```swift
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! chatBubble
```

3. Don't do reinit outgoingMessageView in dequeue cycle

```swift
outgoingMessageView = UIImageView(frame:
                         CGRect(x: self.lblmsg.frame.origin.x,
                                y: self.lblmsg.frame.origin.y,
                                         width: bubbleImageSize.width,
                                         height: bubbleImageSize.height))
```

update frame instead

```swift
outgoingMessageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.lblmsg.frame.origin.x,
                                   y: self.lblmsg.frame.origin.y,
                                   width: bubbleImageSize.width,
                                   height: bubbleImageSize.height)
```

4. Don't add to view hierarchy each time so remove the line

`self.addSubview(outgoingMessageView)`

or add this outgoingMessageView only once in `override func awakeFromNib()` or in `override func prepareForReuse()` or so

5. Make sure that you **NOT** mix autolayout and frame-based approaches. Choose only one of them

Comment: I have added outgoing imageview as iboutlet, changed a piece of code that makes cell duplicate issue. Also i have applied your suggetions .Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Actulally follwing piece of code results in cell duplication.

```
if (arrCell.contains(indexPath.row)) {
    print("Exist")
} else {
    arrCell.append(indexPath.row)
    print("Not exist")
                                               
    cell!.showOutgoingMessage(color: green, text: self.animals[indexPath.row], tag: indexPath.row)
}
```

I removed this piece of code and cell duplication dissappered